"Boost" in German for American license plate
Hello and thank you in advance. I'm looking for the proper way to say "boost" or "boosted" in German as it relates to the boost pressure of a cars turbo charger. The caveat - it's for a Mercedes lecense plate with a limit of 7 characters. I could shorten longer words by removing vowels to make it work. The closest I could find was "auftrieb" or "aufladen." Any insight helps.

In German, one usually finds "Turbo" for cars with turbo charger (if it is mentioned).
If you feel like mentioning the pressure you might add it as trailing numbers like "Turbo2,5" (though it might be interpreted as 2.5 litres of motor volume, too).

You could go with something like "LADEDRUCK", maybe shortened to "LDEDRCK". That directly translates to "boost pressure".
You could also take something along the lines of "aufgeladen" (boosted), maybe as "AUFGLDN"
TURBO would be the term for the actual charger, but sounds somewhat lame, I think (and I guess will be taken already anyhow).
A mechanical booster (non-turbo, Roots, for example) would be a "Kompressor" you could shorten to "KOMPRSSR" or thelikes, but depends if it fits to your actual engine.
Want to have it simpler? Take DRUCK, which means pressure (of all things), so could relate both to your boost pressure and also how you press forward

Most of the "Turbo" combinations will be taken in any sufficiently large US state.
I suggest "Ladedruck" (which means "boost pressure"), you just have to get a little creative with which letters you leave out: "LDDRUCK", "LADEDRK".
Or you state the actual maximum boost pressure, e.g. "2,7 BAR".
